# simulating slow internet connection on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

iam using c#,asp.net and iis, i want to simulate slow internet connection on my pc for testing my app.

is it possible i can control bandwidth of iis.

please dont  suggest

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(someDuration);
```

in c# file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can run Fiddler and use its connection throttling to simulate a slow connection.

Note that you'll need to browse to your machine name, not `localhost`.  (`localhost.` should also work)

Answer (score 5):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could find or create a proxy that provides file-configurable or UI-modifyable speed controls.  The proxy would get the request from the client, make the request to the server, receive the response, then s-l-o-w-l-y send the response to the client.  (It would probaly use some sort of Thread.Sleep(x) in between sending each byte of the response to the client.)

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little on the internet, I found no freeware/FOSS on win32 that does the job for arbitrary ports.

I have a server under tests that listens on port 13000 and a client under test that has a configurable sending port. Many tools, designed for web only, make a throttling tunnel from port 80 to something configurable, but my server will never listen on port 80..

Anyone knows something like unix 'tc' command?

Comment: Did you ever find any software to help you with this?

Comment: No luck, that was long ago and I went another way, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This isn't linked to C#, but I would suggest to slow down the system network (or the vm network ..) instead, it should be much easier to play around.
In linux, we can use **tc**.

> sudo tc qdisc add dev wlp3s0 root netem delay 500ms

To turn it off:

> sudo tc qdisc del dev wlp3s0 root netem

Source: http://jvns.ca/blog/2017/04/01/slow-down-your-internet-with-tc/

https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc